# Merge multiple JSON files and include filename of each file in the resulting object

Tags: json, merge, filenames, jq

I have hundreds of files being named as [guid].json where structure of them all looks similar to this:

```
{
  "Active": true,
  "CaseType": "CaseType",
  "CustomerGroup": ["Core", "Extended"]
}
```

First I need to append a new key-value pair to all files with `"CaseId": "[filename]"` and then merge them all into one big array and save it as a new json manifest file.

I would like one file with the following structure from a jq command:

```
[
  {
    "Active": true,
    "CaseType": "CaseType",
    "CustomerGroup": ["Core", "Extended"],
    "CaseId": "43d47f66-5a0a-4b86-88d6-1f1f893098d2"
  },
  {
    "Active": true,
    "CaseType": "CaseType",
    "CustomerGroup": ["Core", "Extended"],
    "CaseId": "e3x47f66-5a0a-4b86-88d6-1f1f893098d2"
  }
]
```

Comment: But your expected output shows `CaseId` same as `43d47f66-5a0a-4b86-88d6-1f1f893098d2` ? Shouldn't they be unique

Comment: Oh .. typo thx for pointing it out 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`input_filename`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#input_filename).

```
jq -n '[ inputs | .CaseId = input_filename ]' *.json
```

Comment: Just one additional question. Would it be possible to avoid ".json" as part of the CaseId value?

Comment: Sure. Use `(input_filename | rtrimstr(".json"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` adding on one input object at a time. Use `input_filename` to get the UTF-8 encoded filename and form the record with `CaseId`

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $d (null; . + [ $d + { CaseId: input_filename } ] )' *.json
```